# Get HTML control in formview control on server

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a FormView control and html and server control in it. i can find my server control by

```
frm.FindControl("myContorlName");
```

but how get html controls? i know i have html controls in Request object but how get them?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added html controlls with `runat="server"` you can access it with `Request.Form[ControlName.UniqueID]` otherwise, you need to add `name="yourcontrol"` and you will get the controls in `Request.Form["YourControlName"]`.

Comment: tnx, i cant get it from Request but put runat="server" and get it on server, but i defined for my html control(check box) change event has disable by doing this.

Comment: I found unchecked html checkboxs on sever are null (not False!)

Comment: you mean put >clientIDMode="static"< ?! but it is html control. i wanna just run javascript for html control that have runat="server" attribute